# How often do you check for an exception in a C++ new instruction?

Tags: c++, exception

I just started reading Effective C++ today and got to the point where the author talks about the operator new.

The book explains very well how you can catch (with various degrees of elegance) the std::bad_alloc exception that the operator new can raise if you run out of memory.

My question is: How often do you check for the case when there isn't enough memory to instantiate a object, if at all? and why? Is it worth the hassle?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333736/is-out-of-memory-a-recoverable-error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I catch exceptions when I can answer this question:

> What will you do with the exception once you've caught it?

Most of the time, my answer is, "I have no idea. Maybe my caller knows." So I don't catch the exception. Let it bubble up to someone who knows better.

When you catch an exception and let your function proceed running, you've said to your program, "Never mind. Everything's fine here." When you say that, by golly, everything had better be fine. So, if you've run out of memory, then after you've handled `std::bad_alloc`, you should not be out of memory anymore. You shouldn't just return an error code from your function, because then the caller has to check explicitly for that error code, and you're still out of memory. Your handling of that exception should free some memory. Empty some caches, commit some things to disk, etc. But how many of the functions in your program do you really want to be responsible for reducing your program's memory usage?

If you cannot solve the problem that triggered the exception, then do not handle the exception.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that when you run out of memory there is generally not much you can do except write to a crash dump and exit the program. It's therefore useless to check every new in your program.

One exception to this is when you allocate memory for e.g. loading a file, in which case you just need to inform the user that not enough memory is available for the requested operation.

Comment: Well, one techniques some people do is allocate a large chunk on program startup.  Sort of a reservoir for yourself.  Then when the operating system can't help you anymore you have memory of your own.  So no, it isn't true there is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Well -- then you'll run out of OS memory quicker -- and then run out of your own memory. Now there is nothing you can do...

Comment: If you can inform the user there is a problem, and stay alive while the user sees what can be done, then you have done something to solve the problem.

Comment: A possible way to recover may be to try to allocate multiple smaller chunks, as that's more likely to succeed in a fragmented memory space. Or you can just work with a single smaller buffer. (instead of allocating 4GB to store your file, allocate 40MB and swap data in and out as needed)

Comment: jalf : What you're suggestion is changing the memory allocator, this solves only a subset of the possible issues.

Comment: Nowadays, when you run out of memory, you've likely got a nasty leak, and patching it is the only real option.  Changing allocation is not likely to work long.

Comment: There are a lof of reasons for running out of memory that don't include memory leaks, including, but not restricted to, virtual memory fragmentation.

Comment: If you're getting close to using the 2 GB of virtual memory a modern OS then it's time to either start moving stuff to disk or switch to a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Users still run 32-bit OS, you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most important thing is to always be conscious of the possibility you might run out of memory.  Then decide whether you care or not.  Consider trying and catching for each and every allocation -- that's a lot of a hassle.  Pick between increased productivity and simpler code versus an application that can gracefully handle the case of no-memory.  I think both gains are extremely valuable in the right contexts, so choose carefully.

Yes, you can make your life easier by defining a template base-class that provides a custom operator new and operator delete and sets a new new-handler.   Then you can use the [Curiously Recurring Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) pattern to derive from this base class.  Your derived classes will then gracefully handle bad allocations, but you still need to remember to derive from that base-class on each new class you create.  Often you may end up with multiple-inheritance, which may bring complexities of its own.  No matter what you do to handle bad allocations, your code will not be as simple as if you don't bother.

There is never one answer to this.  It is a choice you must make, depending on the context as always.

Answer (score 4):

Never. I have always considered that the default behaviour (there is a std::bad_alloc exception, it is not handled, and thus the program terminates with an error message) is good, for the applications I've worked in.

Comment: What if you want a clean exit?  For example, saving your files (at least a backup)?  What about situations where it can be handled, e.g. tell the user "out of memory" when he tries to save, and suggest resolutions?

Comment: Hmm. In some cases it might pay off to try to do something, but in the specifications I've worked with, an out of memory condition has never been treated.

One more thing - we've had hundreds of bug reports from customers, but not a SINGLE one of them has been out of memory.

Comment: Auto saving backup files should already be happening if the program was in a working state before the OOM crash.

Answer (score 3):

Not handling the exception will crash your program, and the support requests you get will be somewhere between "does not work", "crashes randomly", and "I lost all my work of that day". If you think that's ok, then it's not worth the hassle indeed.

The least you can do is telling the user that he actually ran out of memory indeed, at least giving him (or support) a clue why the application is randomly crashing.

Additionally, you can try to preserve results, e.g. saving them to a recovery file. That might be easier to do before you run into the problem, though.

It would be fabulous if you could go as far as giving an error message like "You cannot insert this image because you ran out of memory". And you'd continue working as if nothing happened. However, this would mean all the code behind a user command must be transactional and give a [strong exception safety guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_safety).

---

So, identify the cost of randomly running out of memory. Based on that, evaluate which "level of protection" you need to give to your user.

Comment: Showing an "out of memory" messagebox is not-trivial! How do you create the messagebox object?!

Comment: You preallocate it. trivial, but not necessarily easy ;)
On Win32, use MessageBox with the MB_SYSTEMMODAL flag.

Answer (score 2):

In a system using virtual memory, `malloc()` won't return `NULL`, and new won't return `std::bad_alloc`; they will return a virtual address. When you write to the memory zone pointed by this address, the system will try to map the virtual address to a physical address. If there's no more memory available, you'll get a page fault.

So you catch for `std::bad_alloc` when you're on an embedded system without MMU, and hope you can do something to free some memory.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily hold true. First, you might run out of (contiguous) adress space, second, many implementations will already commit memory when you do your C++ allocation.

Comment: True for the former. For the latter, could you point me to some implementation docs which explain it ? I thought allocating physical memory only when needed was a widely used technique.

Comment: AFAIK, the "commit on use, not on allocation" is used in some Linux implementations only. For example, Win32 does not use it. If an allocation succeeds in Win32, then the memory is available and reserved.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that's legal for a C++ system.  It may well be that, once the memory is allocated, it must be usable.

Comment: @David: ever since I first heard about it, I've suspected the same thing, that it isn't valid for a C++ implementation to do this. Nevertheless, it's what linux does. Maybe it invokes the fact that it's implicitly "valid" for any implementation to bail out at any time. e.g. power cuts.

Comment: Where "valid" means "the spec doesn't allow it, but it's pointless forbidding it, since some hardware inherently cannot be prevented from just stopping unexpectedly at any time".

Comment: Overcommit a Linux misfeature, turned off by echo "2" >proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory. Under those circumstances, C++ can behave as it should. C++ programs can indeed fail by 'acts of God' like kill -9, and ISO doesn't define that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think this largely depends on the type of applications you write. If i would write something that doesn't affect the global stability of the system, let's say a game or a movie player, i would not check for that exception. My application would call `std::terminate` and i could log it somewhere, or my kernel would kill my program first to make room for other programs.

If i write a program whose stability directly corresponds with the one of the system it runs on, let's say a video driver or an init system, i would check for memory exceptions all the time (probably wrapping allocations in a function), and get some memory from a pre-allocated pool in case of an allocation failure.

I think this all depends on proportionality. What do you gain from a amazingly stable movie player, if it starts slowing down to play movies because of your aggressive checking?

Btw, someone answered malloc won't return 0 when you're out of memory for some systems. That's right, but as the manpage of malloc points out (linux specific)

> In case Linux is employed under circumstances where it would be less desirable to suddenly lose some randomly picked processes, and moreover the kernel version is sufficiently recent, one can switch off this overcommitting behavior using a command like:  `$ echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`
>
> See also the kernel Documentation directory, files vm/overcommit-accounting and sysctl/vm.txt.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to allocate memory for e.g. a path buffer where you know it will be only a few bytes, that may not be worth the hassle.

But when you have to allocate memory for bigger objects like images or files, you definitely should do the check.

Comment: Allocations may fail at any time, and not handling them will crash your application. Granted, large allocations are more likely to crash but that doesn't mean many small ones won't.

Comment: I think he gets that, that's why he's saying it's not worth the hassle for smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not worthwhile unless you're using something like the RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) pattern. In that case you're likely allocating remote resources in the constructor which may include using new to create a large buffer.

In this case, it's probable better to catch the exception as you are in a constructor. Also, since this is in RAII, it's likely just the resource requires too much memory, which allows you to provide the user with more descriptive error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that your program died from swap death way before you allocated your last possible byte, with the harddisk accessing a pagefile the size of your address space. But with modern systems holding 4GB+ yet running 32 bits processes, this behavior is much less common. Even the biggest processes may get all the physical RAM they can handle. In those cases, they can run out of memory before the harddisk dies.

There is no general handling strategy, though. Any process that has caches implemented should flush those - but a good cache would already have been flushed when the OS signalled a low memory condition. A process that responds to user requests can handle bad_alloc at the user request granularity. There's generally little benefit in keeping any memory allocated, if you run out of memory for the user action. Instead, revert to the state before the user action. A non-interactive process on the other hand might switch to from an O(N) to a slower O(N log N) algorithm.