# When would I use bad_typeid?

Tags: c++, exception

When exactly would a bad_typeid exception be used?

Comment: What's wrong with this explanation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/bad_typeid/

Comment: I'm really looking or a more specific situation in which you would use this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of exception generally *wouldn't* be used. Instead, it only exists so that you can *recognize* it. If a tester or user sends you a crash report that mentions `bad_typeid`, you'll know what sort of bug to look for when you start debugging.

You're not really meant to throw this exception yourself, and I don't think you're even meant to catch it, either. After all, what could you possibly do to [resolve the root cause of this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399946/33732#400769) within your program? The way to recover from this type of exception is to find the bug, fix it, recompile, and distribute an updated version of your program that doesn't attempt to use the `typeid` operator on invalid values.

Answer (score 2):

The bad_typeid exception is thrown by the typeid operator when the operand for typeid is a NULL pointer.  In other words, exceptions of class bad_typeid are thrown when typeid is called on a dereferenced null pointer.

- [Apache documentation](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/bad-typeid.html)
- [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywb1hdyh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you think of any specific examples of when you would use this exception? I see the documentation on those pages of how it looks to use it but I'm just looking for a more specific situation in which it would be used.