# resource acquisition failure handling

Tags: exception, dynamic-allocation

After years of programming, I havent had a situation where reasonable malloc or new would fail (maybe because my mallocs are trully reasonable), though I always check for it.

In my case, apps should gracefully (i hope) close with an appropriate log entry. What would you do in this case? Its interesting to hear your approach - do you wait for resources or close the shop?

Comment: It would completely depend on the application, wouldn't it? And once you've settled on your use case, the appropriate mechanism should be obvious. This seems like a bit of a pointless poll to me...

Comment: Gotta agree- this sounds like a subjective poll, and not even language-specific to C or C++.

Comment: I'd like to know the way people think in such situations. Yes, c,c++ is just because i do programming in it

Comment: Related: [Is “Out Of Memory” A Recoverable Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333736/is-out-of-memory-a-recoverable-error)

Comment: @delnan yeah, thanks, could be flagged as a clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's pretty much nothing you can do if dynamic allocation fails- there are pretty much no operations written to handle that situation. If it fails, then just let the app crash.

Comment: with a message in a bottle and captain leaves last thing or just crash?

Comment: @user757808: How can you leave a message in a bottle when you can't allocate a bottle? Your I/O libraries will not, and possibly for a given platform cannot, be designed to operate without dynamic allocation.

Comment: @DeadMG - Maybe look at your core dump?

Comment: This is bogus. Even when a small allocation fails, you should try to exit gracefully; chances are that stack unwinding will free sufficient resources for the I/O library to output the error message, as @Raedwald suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have my program shut-down as gracefully as it can, with *simple* logging of the error message. In C++ I do this by having a `catch` for `std::bad_alloc` in `main()`. By the time the `catch` executes, destructors called by stack unwinding should have freed some memory, so the logging itself is less likely to fail. I avoid memory allocation (for example by using `char *` strings rather than `std::string` strings) in that logging code, to further reduce the chance of the logging failing.