# Creating a C function that initialises a struct and returns back a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C and i'm trying to do the following:

- create a structure `table` from a function
- return `pointer` to the newly created `table`

typedef of table: `typedef char table [8][8];`

So, I created this function:

```
table* create_table() {
  table o;
  return &o;
}
```

But i get an error from compiler saying that I'm returning address of a local variable.

How do I do t o create a `table` from the function and then return the pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot give back the address of a local variable, as the address become invalid one the function (`create_table`) returns, instead, you should create it on the heap:

```
table* create_table() 
{
    table * o;
    o = malloc(sizeof(table));
    // Edit - added initialization if allocation succeeded.
    if (o != NULL)
    {
        memset(o, 0, sizeof(table));
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: ... and you should document in the comment at the top of your `create_table` function (you do have a comment there, right :-) that (a) the function may return NULL if it's unable to allocate memory, and (b) the caller of the function is responsible for calling `free` on the returned `table` when it's no longer needed.

Comment: ... and you should check for a `NULL` return from `malloc` before attempting to fill in the new table's fields.

Comment: @larsmans I doubt this will help, the app will be on a death row

Comment: @Ulterior: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @larsmans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637906/resource-acquisition-failure-handling

Comment: @Ulterior - such (no-)handling will result in undefined behavior. not that recommended...

Comment: @Ulterior: there are lots of applications where out of memory can reasonably be handled. E.g., an interactive program for handling big datasets, where the user doesn't want to see their command history and settings wiped just because they tried to load a file that's too big to handle in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return the address of a local variable. It is deallocted when the function exits. You have to allocate it using malloc and return that pointer. For example:

```
table* ptr = malloc(sizeof(table));
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(table));
return table;
```